# Upload multiple image to server and show it's progress in a recycleview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, image-uploading

Upload multiple image to server and show it's progress in a recycleview in android

I want to show the multiple image uploading progress in a recycleview.

now am using notification for that.

```
 public void uploadMultipart() {


    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    //Uploading code
    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

getPath Method

```
//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

where i change the code. Help me to show the uploading progress in a recycleview.

I want to show the progress of image upload like this in my application.Click
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scsu3.png) for sample screenshot.

Comment: For particular row or as a general in notification bar?

Comment: now in notification bar it's work fine.. but i want to show in my app

Comment: Share snapshot what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want the progress of each image upload in a recycleview with a imageview.

Comment: What networking library are you using for image upload? . You'll need to create callbacks to get the progress of each upload and dynamically update the recyclerview

Comment: am using compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1' lib

Comment: please any one help me to solve...

Comment: @Piyush, i edit the question and add screenshot that i want to achieve. Please check it. thank you in advance.

Comment: please anyone help?